# Error Control Operator ('@') on XAMPP 5.5.19 or above

Tags: php, xampp

I have PHP code like below, which goes well on XAMPP version 5.3 :

```
...
if (!@$this->LDAP_Connection = ldap_connect($this->LDAP_Server, $this->LDAP_Port)) {
  $this->_SetLDAPError();
  return false;
} else {
  ...
}
...
```

But when I switch to XAMPP version 5.5.19, it appears an unknown error.

Is there a mistaken configuration in php.ini file? or

Is there any other way regarding the use of Error Control Operator ('@') in XAMPP version 5.5.19 or above?

I've read the documentation in http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Thank you for taking your time to give me some example code or alter my code in answer comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The XAMPP with PHP version 5.4 or higher need file libsasl.dll inside folder xampp/apache/bin/. The libsasl.dll is already set in folder xampp/php/ when the XAMPP was installed. So I just copy it.

I found this concerning XAMPP where the fix was to move the libsasl.dll out of the xampp/php to the xampp/apache/bin before enabling the ldap extension (http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=185776). I tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

try this hope helps

```
@$this->LDAP_Connection = ldap_connect($this->LDAP_Server, $this->LDAP_Port)
if (!is_object($this->LDAP_Connection)) {
$this->_SetLDAPError();
return false;
} else {
...
}
```